# css child selector select the last div

Tags: css

```
<body>
    <div>content 1</div>
    <div>content 2</div>
    <div>content 3</div>
</body>
```

how do i select the last  tag without using any id or class. I have already tried:

```
body:last-child {
        clear: both;
        background-color:red;
}
```

Please help

Thank you

but it's this is css3 so the browser (ipad safari) does not recoginsed it.

Comment: Be wary of the compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`body:last-child` selects a body tag that is the last child of its parent, try

```
body > :last-child
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Child_selectors) (`>`):

```
body > :last-child {
    clear: both;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: @Wex `*:last-child` is equivalent to `:last-child`.

Answer (score 0):

XXXX:last-child means that XXXX is the last child. So:

```
table tr:last-child { ... }
```

is applied to the last *tr* of the *table*.

In your case:

```
body > :last-child { ... }
```

works because *>* select for you the children of body, then you select the last one with *:last-child*